# J query AJAX get form info?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, key-value

Hi I am trying to get my code to retrieve the key/ value pairs from a form on the page when a user clicks submit. I have been looking around and have tried a bunch of methods but keep getting errors such as :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '6' in success

My Code:

```
 <form action="./blah" id="thisform">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Place a Reservation</legend>
      <label for="firstName">First name: </label>
      <input id="firstName" type="text" placeholder="first name" autofocus="autofocus"
        required="true" pattern="[a-z,A-Z]{8}"/><br/><br/>

      <label for="lastName">Last name: </label>
      <input id="lastName" type="text" placeholder="last name"
        required="true" pattern="[a-z,A-Z]{1, 10}"/><br/><br/>



      <label for="Phone">Phone number: </label>
      <input id="Phone" type="phone-number" placeholder="(000)-000-0000"  maxlength="10" minlength="10"
        required="true" /><br/><br/>

      <label for="Party">For how many people? </label>
      <input id="Party" type="number" placeholder="#" min="1" max="12" value="1"
        required="true"/><br/><br/>

      <label for="date-of">Date of reservation </label>
      <input id="date-of" type="date" placeholder="date of reservation" min="2016-01-01"
        max="2016-12-30" value=""/><br/><br/>

      <label for="Time-of">Time (24hr) </label>
      <input id="Time-of" type="text" placeholder="00:00 "  maxlength="20" /><br/><br/>
      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>



    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

and then the script

```
<script>
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var submit = document.getElementById("submit")

    submit.onclick = function(){
        $.get("reserve.html", function(key, value){
$.each(value, function(key, value){
    console.log(key, value);
});
});
};


    });
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

I am quite lost and I know my code is off by a ways, any help is appreciated!

(also my first name input is not accepting what I enter and im not sure why)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a quit simple. Just use `$('form').serialize()` like this:

```
$.get('reserve.html?'+$(form).serialize());
```